# Error with StackNavigator: Element type is invalid. Got: undefined

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I'm trying to find a bug in my code but after so much time I feel hopeless. Could you help me, please?

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import SickList from './pages/SickList'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


const App = () => {

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Menu = () => {
  return(
<Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={SickList} />
</Stack.Navigator>)
}

return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Menu />
</NavigationContainer> 
)
```

}

```
export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `StackNavigator`.

Comment: Does your SickList.js has default export?

Comment: Yes, it does. Actually, it works fine with TabNavigator. I don't know why it doesn't work with StackNavigator.

Comment: What is version of react native you are using? Miminal requirement is at least react-native@0.63.0. If you're using Expo, your SDK version needs to be at least 41.

Comment: I don't use Expo. I have     "react-native": "0.64.2",     "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",  "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.1",

Comment: I changed to     "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",  and it worked.

Comment: Great, it seemd like some kind of issue with versions. Probably there is some bug in library itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some hours of trying to find out the reason, I tried to change package.json:

I changed to     "react-native": "~0.63.4", "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is causing your issue, but you're missing a closing brace before the last line 'export default App'

Edit: You also might need to wrap your SickList import in braces.

Comment: Thank you! I just forgot to put it here. I have it in my actual code.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is wrapping your SickList import in braces, so do `import { SickList } from './pages/SickList` instead of `import SickList ...`